# How to extract and merge multiple arrays from an array of object containing the array of interest?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this model :

```
export class Category {
    id: number;
    label: String;
    subCategories: SubCategory[];
}

export class SubCategory {
    id: number;
    label: String;
}
```

So for instance I pull this array :

```
data = 
[
      {
        'id': 5,
        'label': 'Audio',
        'subCategories': [{'id': 9, 'label': 'Chinese'}, {'id': 10, 'label': 'English'}]
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'label': 'Video',
        'subCategories': [{'id': 11, 'label': 'Chinese'}, {'id': 12, 'label': 'English'}]
      }
];
```

How do I extract the following array : `["Chinese", "English", "Chinese", "English"]`, namely I want to extract all the `SubCategory[]` from each Category in the original array, grab their label attribute and flatten them in an orderly manner into an array.

The function `flat` returns an error :

> Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'SubCategory[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need flat function. You can use native array method.

```
data.reduce((acc: any, cur: any) => {
  return acc.concat(cur.subCategories.map((v: any) => v.label));
}, []);
```